# DateFormatter.date(from: String) vs Locale

Tags: ios, swift, locale, dateformatter

I'd like to ask for some help understanding what might cause my DateFormatter to fail...

1. App receives data from server as string (ex. "2020-12-13 02:54:36 UTC")
2. App parses string to date
3. App supports English and Spanish localisations (irrelevant?)

---

Code:

DateFormatter (all setup):

> dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"

- generally all dates are returned in UTC but using 'zzz' to also cover other time formats like CDT etc.. we had some mix up on sever side at one point...

Problem:
I've received a single log from a user (using Spanish locale) who experienced date parser failure. But i can't reproduce this anyhow... (phone set to EN / ES - dates parse ok for both UTC and CDT time zones).

Server Response:

> { "creation_date":
> "2021-05-14 06:07:55 UTC", }

where **date(from string:)** returns nil for above date(s).

- Am I doing this wrong?
- Improvements? (i.e. would setting formatter.locale = "en_EN" help? Server date format is fixed.

Comment: you should set the date formatter's locale to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` before setting the `dateFormat`

Comment: Try setting `formatter.locale = "en_US"`